# How do I view the pages and IPs that made the API request

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am starting to go over quota on my geocoding api, and I need to learn which pages on my site are making the requests, and ensure that all requests are coming from the server (or my localhost) IP address. The API console only tells you how many requests are made, but none of this other information, which I know they are logging based on the following in my network tab in chrome console:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent?1shttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ffind_map%3Foptions%255Baction%255D%3Dindex%26options%255Bcontroller%255D%3Ddispensers
```

Comment: By the way, the reason I am not whitelisting IP addresses is because my local IP changes numerous times per day...

Comment: For now I am just logging the page in rails .. but I'll leave this question open as I'm still curious